# How to write custom make_tuple function?

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, c++17

```
struct Person {
    int id;
    std::string name;
    std::string email;
}
```

I want to convert struct to custom tuple like

```
auto tuple<...> my_make_tuple1(const Person& p) {
    return std::make_tuple(p.id);
}
auto tuple<...> my_make_tuple2(const Person& p) {
    return std::make_tuple(p.id, p.name);
}
```

How to write those tuple function?

Comment: Just remove `tuple<...>` part and it should compile.

Comment: remove tuple<...> part works@rustyx

Answer (score 0):

Simpler would be to just use `auto`:

```
struct Person {
    int id;
    std::string name;
    std::string email;
};


auto as_tuple(const Person& p) {
    // return std::tie(p.id, p.name); // Possibly
    return std::make_tuple(p.id, p.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

through this you can make tuple

```
 struct Person {
        int id;
       std::string name;
        std::string email;
    };
    
    
    auto as_tuple(const Person& p) {

        return std::make_tuple(p.id, p.name);
    }
```